# How to Automatically run/stop a script at a certain time of the day

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, sh

What I want to achieve:

8:00 AM:
Runs a sh script (this script does not stop running until the user presses ctrl+c)

8:00 PM:
stops the script by sending ctrl+c or other means

Repeat

I tried researching crontab but I'm not sure about the *stop script at 8 pm* part.

Comment: Scripts can be terminated by other scripts. See `man kill`

Comment: Have script 1 write its PID (process ID) into a file somewhere: `cat "$$" > /path/to/myPID`.  Script 2 reads that file and kills the process with that PID: `kill $(cat /path/to/myPID)`. Try it out.

Comment: Systemd can do that.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way.
It turns out that the script I'm running is a nodejs program.
So here's my solution:
Script 1:
Infinite loop
If time is in the right interval to start script:
npm start
sleep

Script 2:
Infinite loop
If time is in the interval to stop the script:
killall npm
sleep